# Android socket connection with PC works on Emulator but not on Device

Tags: android, sockets

I have a little example running that sends a message through a socket from an Android device to the PC.
The server is in C++ using an example from [this](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/win/misc/sockets.html) link and the client is a simple Android app.

The problem that I have is that when I run both on my PC (android app on Eclipse's emulator) it works correctly, but when I use an android device I keep getting a java.net.ConnectException due to a connection time out.

At first I thought it could be a firewall problem but I created a rule allowing communication through the port that I am using and things kept working in the same way. I tried to switch off the firewall just in case and nothing happened.

I have pinged the PC from Android and viceversa and everything is fine.

Any ideas on what can I be missing? Both devices are on the same network of course!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appeared to be some kind of firewall blocking incoming requests other than that of Windows. I tried the other way around, starting the communication from Windows' side and everything works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think it is not a good idea to mix between Java and C++ data through Sockets (I am not sure if ints, floats and that sort are going to be equal in both sides).

Nevertheless, have you given internet permission in the Android XML Manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Could you please give us more details about the Server and the Android code?

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the answer.. Im just sending strings and it works perfectly when running on the pc and Eclipse's emulator. Regarding the code, the link to the server is on the question and my android client is as every client around on the web.. Opening the socket with the addressof the server and port.. Running on an asynctask of course. I'll try to post it later I'm on my phone right now :)